# Inline variables view not showing up in WebStorm 9

Tags: webstorm

So I fired up the new WebStorm 9 this morning excited about the new inline variable view in debugging, but I'm not seeing the values.

Do I need to do anything special to enable this? I'm debugging using Karma + Jasmine + Firefox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to be able to see the inline variables, I have to either:

- be in "Live Debug" mode using a "JavaScript Debug" run configuration
- be in test Debug mode using Karma's run configuration

Then set a breakpoint and make sure the code hits it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old issue for you right now, but I ran in the same problem. After some research I found that you are expected to set breakpoints and the application have to stop on them in order to show the inline variables.